# Datatables generate column and get row id Server-side

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables, server-side, datatables-1.10

I have got a datatable using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) server-side. I have created and filled the table as shown below. Now I need to generate column with button but i need to have the id of the row ..

My data returned :

```
{"data":[{"id":"13","name":"gerrard","adress":"new york"}, .... }
```

I want something like if i click in this button it show me the id of the row .. 
There is my code :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>adress</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "server-side-process",
            },

        "columns": [
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "adress" },
                ]
    } );

} );
```

I found this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html) in the documentation but i cant get the id from the data returned .. it is possible to do it please ? thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) property:

```
"render": function ( data, type, full) {
            return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-id=" + full[3] + ">PAY</button>";
    }
```

The `full` parameter is the full datasource for the data row, so you can access it by index.  In your case you would use `full[0]` as it's in the first position.

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/L6omgf1y/4/) which uses different data, but you should be able to see how it works.

Comment: Add `"orderable": false,` to the init code: [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/L6omgf1y/5/)